# Show list / array after IF

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets

I need help with showing a list of items as shown in cell D3 of this doc. I don't know if the `if` statement is adequate for this.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1voFZlpCpa3feHj5vJZ_R30KIP_fV9oCA9ndlptnk350/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=FILTER(A2:B, A1:B1=D1&" "&E1)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
=IFS(E1= 1, JOIN(",",A2:A5),E1= 2, JOIN(",",B2:B5))
```

Thanks

Comment: Please use code tags for stuff like that